# C# Parse Json with multiple objects and arrays newtonsoft

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I'm attempting to parse a rather convoluted/unnecessarily complicated JSON output using newtonsoft in C# however for some reason my parser always returns null. I have searched all over SO and cant't seem to find a solution.

An example of a JSON file I'm trying to parse:

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "d": {
    "gameData": {
      "MJ2Y7tDg": {
        "scores": [
          {
            "max": 1.83,
            "avg": 1.73,
            "rest": 2,
            "active": true,
            "scoreid": "2c556xv464x0x4vtqc"
          },
          {
            "max": 3.47,
            "avg": 3.24,
            "rest": 2,
            "active": true,
            "scoreid": "2c556xv498x0x0"
          },
          {
            "max": 6.06,
            "avg": 5.08,
            "rest": 1,
            "active": true,
            "scoreid": "2c556xv464x0x4vtqd"
          }
        ],
        "count": 62,
        "highlight": [
          false,
          true
        ]
      },
      "jZICYUQu": {
        "scores": [
          {
            "max": 2.25,
            "avg": 2.13,
            "rest": null,
            "active": true,
            "scoreid": "2c5guxv464x0x4vuiv"
          },
          {
            "max": 3.55,
            "avg": 3.29,
            "rest": null,
            "active": true,
            "scoreid": "2c5guxv498x0x0"
          },
          {
            "max": 3.9,
            "avg": 3.33,
            "rest": null,
            "active": true,
            "scoreid": "2c5guxv464x0x4vuj0"
          }
        ],
        "count": 62,
        "highlight": [
          false,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what i have so far, I am very new to JSON wrangling :)

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public int success { get; set; }
        public List<d> d { get; set; }
    }

    public class d
    {
        public List<gameData> gameData { get; set; }
    }

    public class gameData
    {
        public IDictionary<string, Score> gameData{ get; set; }
        public List<scores[]> GameList;
    }
    public class Score
    {
        public double max { get; set; }
        public double avg { get; set; }
        public int rest { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string scoreid { get; set; }
    }
```

Anyone with more JSON wrangling experience know how to get this working?

Thankyou in advanced.
P.S I am currently in high school, learning C#

Comment: please show your code

Comment: he shows the code of the classes he tries to deserialize into, what else is necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parser returns null because structure of your classes doesn't correctly resemble the structure of JSON. The correct structure of classes would be:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int success { get; set; }
    public Class_d d { get; set; }
}

public class Class_d
{
    public Dictionary<string, GameData> gameData { get; set; }
}

public class GameData
{
    public List<Score> scores { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public bool[] highlight { get; set; }
}

public class Score
{
    public decimal max { get; set; }
    public decimal avg { get; set; }
    public int? rest { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string scoreid { get; set; }
}
```

and you can use it as follows:

```
string json = "..."; // the JSON in your example
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you Felix-b . One more thing how would I go about dumping the data, using console.writeline.

Comment: The above code doesn't work. Class_d cannot be parsed. GameData & Score are fine.